# What is the signature for "getRedisPool"?

Tags: java, jedis

After upgrading the jedis version(2.7.3), I'm getting "Incompatible argument to function".

Can you please tell me the signature for "getRedisPool" method?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you, but I can tell you exactly where it is shown to you: in the line right after the line saying "incompatible argument to function."